# change format of label from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy in xamrin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to convert the format of a date in xaml by below code but it reponse nothing. I am sharing my xaml code. Thanks in advance.

```
 <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                                   FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="0" 
                                                   Grid.Column="1" 
                                                   Text="{Binding SaleDate, StringFormat='{0:MMMM d, yyyy}'}"                                                      
                                                   Padding="-15,0,0,0"></Label>
```

[image]

Comment: that appears correct, is `SaleDate` a `DateTime`?

Comment: `MMMM d` is not what you want, `d` means the default short date format that you are seeing. Add another `d`:  `MMMM dd`.

Comment: @Jason no it is string

Comment: you can't use date formats with a string, only with DateTime.  You should never store date objects as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string format is wrong. Use this string format. this will convert DateTime to dd-mm-yyyy format

```
StringFormat='{00:dd-MM-yyyy}'
```

don't create converter if you can get solution on XAML itself